# Debugging a "remote" Android device with Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, vmware, xamarin, virtualization

So I am needing to do some debugging with Xamarin Android. This wouldn't be such a problem if the emulator wasn't so slow. So, I looked at setting up the x86 emulator, but because I'm running Xamarin within VMWare (host machine is Linux), that won't work. My best bet is to install either the x86 accelerated android, or use something like Android-x86 from my host machine.

How could I get Xamarin to connect to a device that not's running on the same machine though?

Comment: I to am using Xarmin and I found that coding on an emulator was painful. I strongly recomend you debug on a phone if you have access to one.

Comment: I do, but I never had any luck getting Xamarin debugging to work on a physical device either :/ Currently chasing down how to fix one of it's many bugs that's completely blocking me from doing anything though

Comment: Are you using the xarmin IDE?

Comment: I'm using both XamarinStudio and Visual Studio... right now, Visual Studio can't open any Xamarin projects though for some reason (just constant "waiting for background operation to complete")

Comment: I have a Nexus 4 phone I can test it on, but I've never had any luck with getting debugging to work right. I *can* deploy release applications and such through Xamarin, but debugging them never works. Breakpoints and such are just never hit

Comment: Did u enable debuggin on ur phone?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to configure ADB to debug over the network instead of USB. Check out Xamarin's document titled [Setup Device for Development](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/set_up_for_device_development), and scroll down to the section titled **Connect the Device to Computer** for directions on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic but have you enabled USB debugging on your Android phone?

http://www.wugfresh.com/faq/how-do-i-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4-2-the-developer-options-menu-item-is-gone/

follow those instructions if you havent...